# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.jalin.bank.model.Trx

Tags: java, hql

My SQL goes like this `select trx_date, card_number , count(card_number) as amount from trx_data_cons where trx_date ='161222' group by trx_date, card_number;`

trx_date || card_number || amount

`YYmmdd      xxxxx         x`

and my HQL is like this

```
public List<Trx> listTrx() {

        List<Trx> list = (List<Trx>) getHibernateTemplate().find(
              "select trxD, trxC, count(trxC) from Trx where trxD = '161222' group by trxD, trxC");
    return list;
    }
```

My Trx.java is

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return " || " + trxD+" || "+ trxC + " ||";
    }
```

but how and where should i put the result of the count??

my main class is

```
List<Trx> list = trxBo.listTrx();
        for(Trx t1:list) {
            System.out.println(t1.toString());
        }
```

i mean, i should define the count right? put it in the model..? but how to retrieve the result of the count??

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma between `trxC` and `count(` :

```
"select trxD, trxC count(trxC) from Trx where trxD = '161222' group by trxD, trxC"
```

should be

```
"select trxD, trxC, count(trxC) from Trx where trxD = '161222' group by trxD, trxC"
```

Comment: It fixed the error that this question was originally about; this is now something totally different.  Can you edit the question to add the Trx class?

Comment: I’m off now, so in the meantime I would also add “AS” clauses to the HQL to make the result set column names match the names of the properties in Trx.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are querying specific fields of an entity (and in this case, also an aggregation i.e. count), you'll get a `List<Object[]>` and not `List<trx>`. Hence the cast exception.

You can however define a DTO which just has the specific fields that you are querying from Trx entity (assuming trxD and trxC are of type String)

```
public class DTO {
     private String trxD;
     private String trxC;
     private Long countTrxC;
}
```

and then use a ResultTransformer to transform the query results into the DTO class objects.

```
public List<DTO> getTrxData() {
     String queryStr = "select trx.trxD as trxD, trx.trxC as trxC, count(trx.trxC) as countTrxC from Trx trx where trx.trxD = '161222' group by trx.trxD, trx.trxC";
     Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryStr);
     query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(DTO.class));
     return query.list();
}
```